# Thread-safe way to funnel data from multiple go routines

Tags: go

Given the following example: http://play.golang.org/p/owvJ8Oi77S

```
func produce(dataChannel chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        dataChannel <- i
    }
}

func main() {
    dataChannel := make(chan int)

    go produce(dataChannel)
    go produce(dataChannel)
    go produce(dataChannel)

    for i := 0; i < 30; i++ {
        data := <-dataChannel
        fmt.Printf("%v ", data)
    }
}
```

Is my assumption that writing to a channel from multiple go routines unsafe correct?

Is there a common/idiomatic way to do this safely? I know you can make a separate channel for each routine that's producing data, I was just wondering if that was the cleanest solution or if there are other alternatives.

Comment: The only thing special about a channel in this regard is that they can only be closed once and nothing can be sent after the channel is closed.  To understand this better, try modifying your example so that you range over the channel instead of a fixed size and work until they're done.  Slightly trickier, but that's a good thing to understand.

Comment: Yeah, my main worry was writing to the same channel from multiple routines/threads. It wasn't clear to me that it was safe to do that.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Channels are completely thread safe.  They are the official way to communicate between goroutines.  I see nothing wrong with your code.  This is the beauty of Go.

Comment: can you please add a link to supporting documentation of "channels are completely thread safe"? I'd like to read that part thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Channels are intended to be shared between threads (and this is the normal meaning of "being thread-safe"). Using channels means you DON'T have shared memory, with the race hazards that you would risk. So Daniel's answer is correct: use channels because that's what they're for.

But note that goroutines create networks of communicating sequential processes that **can sometimes deadlock** if there's a design mistake. They can also livelock (same thing but being busy).

There is a considerable body of knowledge on how to avoid deadlock/livelock. Much of it is from the days when Occam was popular in the '80s and '90s. There are a few special gems from people such as Jeremy Martin ([Design Strategy for Deadlock-Free
Concurrent Systems](http://wotug.ukc.ac.uk/parallel/theory/formal/csp/jeremy-martin/)), Peter Welch ([Higher Level Paradigms](http://kar.kent.ac.uk/21094/1/HigherWelch.pdf)) and others.